# How to find the most popular Foursquare venue in each category in a given city?

Tags: api, foursquare

According to Foursquare API, [Venues/Explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore.html) returns a list of recommended venues near the current location, [Venues/Search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html) returns a list of venues near the current location, optionally matching the search term. So in both cases, the return-list is the collection of venues near the current location. Not the global collection for a given city. In this case, how does ['Plan my next trip'](http://www.my-next-trip.com/) find the most suitable place for each category in a given city? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send a geocodable string (such as the city name) as the `near` parameter in the Search API, leaving the `ll` (lat/long) parameter empty. This will search in the entire city and *not* rank results by distance to a specific point.

From the [docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search):

```
near    Chicago, IL
```

> required unless ll is provided. A string naming a place in the world.
>   If the near string is not geocodable, returns a failed_geocode error.
>   Otherwise, searches within the bounds of the geocode. Adds a geocode
>   object to the response. (Required for query searches)

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the latitude and the longitude using the *ll* parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Let me clarify the question: since 4sq restricts you to specify (lat, lng) pair for search & explore, how do you do the global search with the given city's (lat, lng) pair? I guess it's just about playing with big values of radius parameter. Anything else?

Comment: You have to find out the latitude and the longitude of the city first !

Comment: After playing around w/ 4sq API, I see that 'Plan my next trip' uses the (latitude, longitude) pair and makes an 'explore' API call to 4sq, and picks the top most result from each of these 6 categories : 'food', 'outdoor', 'coffee', 'nightlife', 'shops', 'art & entertainment'. I was looking for alternative approaches. Let's say, the user inputs his start & end (lat, lon) pair in the given city, then to find the best itinerary we would have to search around starting point, ending point, and anything in between. Thanks anyway, Ben :P